# Loading data from a JSON file

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I am trying to get some data from a JSON file. Here is the code for it -

```
import csv
import json
ifile  = open('facebook.csv', "rb")
reader = csv.reader(ifile)

rownum = 0
for row in reader:
    try:
        csvfile = open('facebook.csv', 'r')
        jsonfile = open('file.json', 'r+')
        fieldnames = ("USState","NOFU2008","NOFU2009","NOFU2010", "12MI%", "24MI%")
        reader = csv.DictReader( csvfile, fieldnames)
        for row in reader:
            json.dump(row, jsonfile)
            jsonfile.write('\n')
        data = json.load(jsonfile)
        print data["USState"]
    except ValueError:
        continue
```

I am not getting any output on the console for the print statement. The JSON is in the following format

```
{"USState": "US State", "12MI%": "12 month increase %", "24MI%": "24 month increase %", "NOFU2010": "Number of Facebook UsersJuly 2010", "NOFU2008": "Number of Facebook usersJuly 2008", "NOFU2009": "Number of Facebook UsersJuly 2009"}
{"USState": "Alabama", "12MI%": "109.3%", "24MI%": "400.7%", "NOFU2010": "1,452,300", "NOFU2008": "290,060", "NOFU2009": "694,020"}
```

I want to access this like NOFU2008 for all the rows.

Comment: Is your JSON formatted that exact way? It's not valid JSON. It needs to be in an array.

Comment: @Shadaez - Yes I just copy pasted the first two lines of my JSON file in this question. Does that mean I am making an error in creating the JSON file? I am extracting things from a CSV file and creating a JSON file in that for loop

Comment: Yeah, I'd first write a '[' then whenever you write a row add a ',' before the new line, except on the last row where you'll just add a ']'. You'll want to read each value in the array, too, so `for line in data` `data["USState"]`

Comment: If you're unsure if it's correct, throw the created JSON into jsonlint.com and validate. It'll tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Oops, that comments meant to say `line["USState"]`
I'm unfamiliar with python's json lib but i do know that those two lines aren't formatted right.

Comment: You have just written something into `jsonfile` so the file pointer is at the end of the file. Of course `json.load(jsonfile)` should load nothing from the end of the file...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the way you're creating the JSON file. You don't want to use `json.dump()` for each row and then append those to the JSON file.

To create a JSON file, you should first create a data structure in Python that represents the entire file the way you want it, and then call `json.dump()` one time only to dump out the entire structure to JSON format.

Making a single `json.dump()` call for your entire file will insure that it is valid JSON.

I'd also recommend wrapping your list/array of rows inside a dict/object so you have a place to put other properties that pertain to the entire JSON file as opposed to a single row.

It looks like the first couple of rows of your facebook.csv are something like this (with or without the quotes):

```
"US State","12 month increase %","24 month increase %","Number of Facebook UsersJuly 2010","Number of Facebook usersJuly 2008","Number of Facebook UsersJuly 2009"
"Alabama","109.3%","400.7%","1,452,300","290,060","694,020"
```

Let's say we want to generate this JSON file from that (indented here for clarity):

```
{
    "rows": [
        {
            "USState": "US State",
            "12MI%": "Number of Facebook usersJuly 2008",
            "24MI%": "Number of Facebook UsersJuly 2009",
            "NOFU2010": "Number of Facebook UsersJuly 2010",
            "NOFU2008": "12 month increase %",
            "NOFU2009": "24 month increase %"
        },
        {
            "USState": "Alabama",
            "12MI%": "290,060",
            "24MI%": "694,020",
            "NOFU2010": "1,452,300",
            "NOFU2008": "109.3%",
            "NOFU2009": "400.7%"
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that the top level of the JSON file is an object (not an array), and this object has a `rows` property which is the array of rows.

We can create this JSON file and test it with this Python code:

```
import csv
import json

# Read the CSV file and convert it to a list of dicts
with open( 'facebook.csv', 'rb' ) as csvfile:
    fieldnames = (
        "USState", "NOFU2008", "NOFU2009", "NOFU2010",
        "12MI%", "24MI%"
    )
    reader = csv.DictReader( csvfile, fieldnames )
    rows = list( reader )

# Wrap the list inside an outer dict
wrap = {
    'rows': rows
}

# Format and write the entire JSON in one fell swoop
with open( 'file.json', 'wb' ) as jsonfile:
    json.dump( wrap, jsonfile )

# Now test the file by reading it and parsing it
with open( 'file.json', 'rb' ) as jsonfile:
    data = json.load( jsonfile )

# For fun, convert the data back to JSON again and pretty-print it
print json.dumps( data, indent=4 )
```

A few notes... This code does not have the nested reader loops from the original. I have no idea what those were for. One reader should be enough.

In fact, this version doesn't use a loop at all. This line generates a list of rows from the reader object:

```
    rows = list( reader )
```

Also pay close attention to use use of `with` where the CSV and JSON files are opened. This is a great way to open a file because the file will be automatically closed at the end of the `with` block.

Now having said all this, I have to wonder if this exact JSON structure is what you really want? It looks like the first row of the CSV is a header row, so you may want to skip that row? You can do that easily by adding a `reader.next()` call before converting the rest of the CSV data to a list:

```
reader.next()
    rows = list( reader )
```

Also I'm not sure I understand how you want to access the resulting data. You wouldn't be able to use `data["USState"]`, because `USState` is a property of each individual row object. So say a little more about how you want to access the data and we can sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a list of json objects in the file then you should inform yourself about what a list in json looks like.

In case that list elements are separated by a comma you should put something like this into the code:

```
jsonfile.write(',\n')
```